# Firewall on an ASUS RT-AC1200G+ router

Tags: router

I've got an Apache server running on a laptop wirelessly connected to my router. It is running on port 90.

In my router settings I have port forwarded port 90 to the laptop's local IP address. When I turn off the firewall for the router, the request to the laptop goes through, and I can connect from any WAN computer. However, that's obviously not how I want my router to be set up (without a firewall).

Here is the problem: When I try to add an inbound firewall rule to accept incoming traffic for the laptop's IP address and port 90 it pops up an error saying "Invalid IP address". Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You said you're doing port forwarding, which means you're doing NAT (technically NAPT), so your laptop's IP is a private IP, not a publicly routable IP. So you need to open port 90 on your router/firewall's own publicly routable IP address (that is, it's WAN address). Without the firewall code blocking these packets, the NAT's port forwarding code will be able to get these packets and forward them along to your laptop.

Comment: So how would I go about doing that :) ?

Comment: Use your router's setttings page to look at its WAN port IP address, and then go to the firewall page and open port 90 on that address. I don't know the exact details of your router's admin web UI, so I can't give you a step-by-step guide.

Comment: Is this where i'm suppose to open port 90?

https://i.imgur.com/ljhWP7V.jpg

Comment: Yes, at the bottom of that page, add an inbound rule allowing all remote IP addresses to connect to your router's WAN IP address, port 90/TCP.

Comment: okey, then I was on the right track from the start, the problem is that it says that the ip adress is invalid.

Comment: So, it says that the IP address is invalid, even when you use the router's WAN IP address instead of the laptop's IP address? How are you filling out the "Remote IP" field? Is there any chance it's balking at the remote address, not the local address?

Comment: So I know it's the local ip adress field that is failing, because i'm not filling out the remote ip field, and the error says *local ip adress* is invalid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65990/discussion-between-spiff-and-aplex).